# IEDriver crashing on switch_to_window()

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-11

So I know IE Driver has a truckload of issues right now, but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem. I've turned on all Protected Modes, and turned off Enhanced Protection.

So here is my code where I'm having an issue.

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("clients_advsearch").click()
handles = browser.window_handles

## find new popup window
new_handle = []
if handles[0] == browser.current_window_handle:
   new_handle = handles[1]
else:
new_handle = handles[0]

browser.switch_to_window(new_handle)  ## either doesn't go to next step if it goes to new window, or goes to next step with the bad handle
browser.switch_to_frame("frameWCSet")  ## doesn't find the frame if on the right page, or doesn't find it at all since its on the wrong page
```

From here, I don't how to proceed with IEDriver. This worked fine in Chromium, but apparently IEDriver is a completely different beast, and I'm forced to use IE for this task.

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and I've followed all recommendations from the Github/googlecode issues pages without avail.

EDIT : If it can help, my handles disappear once in a while as well.

Comment: What version of `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a19f07aec61d491fa4839c002d65d03347fc21e8/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py).
`switch_to_window()` and `switch_to_frame()` are deprecated. See the [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=switch#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_window)

Use

```
driver.switch_to.window
```

and

```
driver.switch_to.frame
```

And,

```
browser.current_window_handle:
```

does not return the list of ALL window handles. It returns only the current handle. So, you should be using

```
window_handles
```

Please refer to the doc

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error from using browser.switch_to.window(new_window), it doesn't go to the next step after going to this new window.

Comment: I'm printing the list with "handles = browser.window_handles", then comparing the current handle with the list, to return the popup with my if statement , am I not?

Comment: I found a different, unrelated workaround, since I couldn't switch windows, I thank you for your help, I can't upvote due to rep score, but I will once I increase it!

Comment: What is the different may I ask?

Comment: Instead of going through the new popup page to click the link, I copied the new page address that I needed and was able to get to this new page.